# undefined local variable or method `render'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

I am getting the following error in my rspec code

```
undefined local variable or method `render'
```

here is my code:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "messages/show.html.erb" do
   it "displays the text attribute of the message" do
    render
    rendered.should contain("Hello world!")
  end
end
```

this is from the book : The RSpec book
below is what i added to Gemfile.

```
group :development , :test do
   gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0"
   gem "webrat", ">= 0.7.2"
end
```

I have not added the file show.html.erb to the views/messages  but i should be getting another error , not this

The strange thing is that this worked on my machine some time before. I deleted the project and created another one and now it just wouldn't work

I had issued these commands after editing the gemfile

```
bundle install
script/rails generate rspec:install
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 10):

For me the answer was to change

```
describe "messages/show.html.erb" do
```

to

```
describe "messages/show.html.erb", type: :view do
```

Answer (score 6):

If your show.html.erb_spec.rb file contains:

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'
```

try changing it to:

```
require 'rails_helper.rb'
```

Explanation:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a closing quote on the first line of your code:

require 'spec_helper

Comment: Nopes ....i probably missed that while copy-pasting it here ... It is not missing on the source code. I am going to edit the question. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

you could change your test like following:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "messages/show.html.erb" do
  it "displays the text attribute of the message" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:message) # or an other test data creator gem
    visit "/messages/1"
    page.should have_content("Hello world!")
  end
end
```